# slqalchemy orm using select where with parameters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying something really simple, but I cannot find the proper way to do it in any of the sqlalchemy orm tutorials I can find. I want to do the equivalent of the following from Adonisjs:

```
Database.query('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE user = ? AND age = ?', ['Tester', 18])
```

How do I do parameters in the below sqlalchemy python code? What am I doing wrong?

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://test:test@localhost:5432/test", echo=False, future=True)
session = Session(engine)

sql = select(User).where(User.first_name == 'Tester').where(User.age == 18)
user = session.execute(sql)
```

So instead of User.first_name == 'Tester', I'd like it to be a binding placeholder. Same goes for User.age == 18. Then is session.execute(sql) I'd like to add the bindings. Is there a way to do this, or am I approaching this the incorrect way? I want to use orm, so the syntax above. I'm trying to learn the newest sqlalchemy with orm instead of core.

Comment: You can use variables instead of literals. `User.first_name = fname`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, bind parameters like the ones in your qmark style query are only available on text based queries like a [`TextClause`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause).

ORM and textual queries are compatible via [`Select.from_statement`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.from_statement).

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    age = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User(first_name={self.first_name}, age={self.age})"

engine = sa.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True, future=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

u1 = User(first_name="Alice", age=21)
u2 = User(first_name="Bob", age=20)

session = orm.Session(engine)

session.add_all([u1, u2])

session.flush()

stmt = sa.select(User).from_statement(
    sa.text("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name = :fn AND age = :age")
)
session.execute(stmt, {"fn": "Alice", "age": 21}).scalars().one()

stmt = sa.select(User).where(User.first_name == "Alice", User.age == 21)
session.execute(stmt).scalars().one()

# or with variables
fn = "Alice"
age = 21
stmt = sa.select(User).where(User.first_name == fn, User.age == age)
session.execute(stmt).scalars().one()
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew you could use from_statement. However, I found it odd that the new(ish) tutorials for ORM (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/quickstart.html#simple-select) show using the syntax the way I have it, but the only way to use the syntax is to hard code values?? That's not good practice and not useful at all. I'll keep digging around to see if I can find something, but for now I will use what you gave me. Thanks!!

Comment: @JustMe - "but the only way to use the syntax is to hard code values??" - No, of course not. If we have a variable named `adult_age = 21` then we can `select(User).where(User.age == adult_age)`

Comment: @GordThompson I know you can do that, but doesn't that introduce sql injection issues? Bindings are the way to go to avoid that.

Comment: @JustMe No, that's the whole point, it'll do the same thing as bound params.

Comment: ( cc: @JustMe ) - In fact, "under the hood" it's *exactly* the same because ORM converts the query into a Core construct. `print(select(User).where(User.age == adult_age))` displays `SELECT "user".id, "user".name, "user".age FROM "user" WHERE "user".age = :age_1`. The parameter substitution takes place when we `.execute()` it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```py
modes = db_session.query(Product)\
    .from_statement(
        sa.text(
            '''
            select * 
            from products p 
            join product_to_categories pc
                on p.id = pc.product_id 
                    and pc.category_id = :category_id
            '''
        ).bindparams(category_id=category_id),
    )
```

Just use `bindparams`